# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 [104]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a flask-sqlalchemy project running on an Azure Web App Service plan using a Linux machine. It is connecting to an Azure SQL DB (SQL Server). Intermittently I am receiving the error below:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 (104) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

This error is being raise from the execution of a select query on the database.

Comment: Did you search google for the error? I found https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/427

Comment: [mcve] please? What is an Azure DB? MSSQL aka. SQLServer? M(aria|y)SQL?

Comment: Yes i have googled the error, there is not a solution in that link.

Comment: It is impossible to tell whether that's a bug in your code or somewhere else with the info you provide. Depending on that, either file a new bug ticket (or update the existing one) or fix your own code, but for a start you need to provide enough instructions how to reproduce it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65329179/2144390 https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/680

Comment: Any solution to this issue?

Comment: @Gord Thompson these are not helpful links - you're linking to a github issue that doesn't resolve the issue beyond saying "look elsewhere", and another SO post that gives vague answers and just links to the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error calling the function pd.read_sql using pandas 1.4.3.

I try to load a huge database table.

The error occurs only sporadically so I ended up putting my code in a while loop that is executed for n times.

**This seems to be a bug in the library.**